# Why am I getting a PDF file filled with 'blob' instead of the expected content when generating in Apps Script after script ownership transfer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, blob, pdf-generation

### Summary

I have a spreadsheet full of sheets of same type, which describe a business object (let's say invoices for example). In each invoice sheet I put a checkbox. When checked, it raises an installed trigger which calls a "save on GDrive" function.
This function takes the export link of given sheet, performs a `UrlFetchApp.fetch` call, then a `HTTPResponse.getBlob`, then a `.createFile(String, Blob, MimeType.PDF)`.
When I developed the apps script, everything was working lile a charm.
Since I transferred the ownership of spreadsheet/apps script, and the final user installed its own trigger, it messed up: my pdf files are only 4 bytes big, and contain only the literal word `"blob"`, while in previous context it contained the pdf view of invoice described by the sheet.

I don't understand what I missed, as the file is well created, and the sheet/script have the same authorizations in `appsscript.json`. So it seems there is something missing at account level, but can't figure what it could be.

### Functional context:

Let's call me (the developer) Flynn, and Alan as the final user for comprehension sake.

Regarding accounts information:

1. I always worked on final Alan's GDrive: when I developed the script, I was already saving files on his drive. So sheet belonged to Flynn but was working on Alan's drive, which was shared with me.
2. When everything was finalized, I transferred script and sheet ownership to Alan, which accepted it.
3. So now the sheet, the script, the drive do belong to Alan
4. Alan installed the same trigger than I did to have the files created as belonging to him.
5. When Alan clicks on the checkbox in the invoice sheet, the PDF file is well created on Alan's drive (which suggests authorizations are good enough), but only contains 4 bytes: the literal word `"blob"`. But at the same time:

   1. `Logger.log(HTTPresponse.getResponseCode());` logs '200' (ok)
   2. `Logger.log(responseFromServer.getBlob().getDataAsString();` logs the normal blob contents, with expected data in it.
   3. It makes it clear this is during the file creation/filling which issue occurs.

Expected behaviour: *The expected behaviour is to have the PDF file properly filled.*

---

### Technical context:

Here is the part of code which issue occurs in:

```
function saveEntityIntoGDrivePDF(entitySheet) {
  const entitysBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const paramSheet = entitysBook.getSheetByName("General configuration");
  const entitysStorageFolderOnGDriveId = paramSheet.getRange('B30').getValue();
  const entitysStorageFolderOnGDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById(entitysStorageFolderOnGDriveId);
  const authorizationToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const exportLink = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+entitysBook.getId()+"/export?format=pdf&size=a4&portrait=true&scale=4&top_margin=1.00&bottom_margin=1.00&left_margin=0.50&right_margin=0.50&gridlines=false&printnotes=false&pageorder=2&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&vertical_alignment=TOP&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&fzr=false&fzc=false&attachment=false&r1=0&r2=40&c1=1&c2=6&gid="+entitySheet.getSheetId();
  const entityHasBeenClosed = entitySheet.getRange('K26').getValue();
  const entityYear = entitySheet.getRange('J5').getValue();
  const entityMonth = entitySheet.getRange('N6').getValue();
  const buddyFirstName = entitySheet.getRange('J10').getValue();
  const buddyLastName = entitySheet.getRange('J9').getValue();
  const entityIndex = entitySheet.getRange('J7').getValue();
  const exportParams = {
    method:"GET",
    headers:{Authorization:"Bearer "+authorizationToken},
    muteHttpExceptions:true
  };
  var success;
  var entityPDFFileName = "";
  if ( entityHasBeenClosed ) {
    entityPDFFileName = "Entity_Closed_"+entityYear+"_"+entityMonth+"_"+buddyLastName+"_"+buddyFirstName+"_"+entityIndex+".pdf";
  }
  else {
    entityPDFFileName = "Entity_Ongoing_"+entityYear+"_"+entityMonth+"_"+buddyLastName+"_"+buddyFirstName+"_"+entityIndex+".pdf";
  }
  if ( !driveFileExists(entitysStorageFolderOnGDrive,entityPDFFileName) ) {
    var responseFromServer = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportLink, exportParams);
    Logger.log(responseFromServer.getBlob().getDataAsString())
    var entityPDFContent = responseFromServer.getBlob().setName(entityPDFFileName);
    entitysStorageFolderOnGDrive.createFile(entityPDFFileName, entityPDFContent, MimeType.PDF);
    success = true;
  }
  else {
    success = false;
  }
  return success;
}
```

Here is an extract of my `appsscript.json`'s content:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ]
}
```

Comment: As written in the linked question's answer, there's no method signature for `createFile(String, Blob, MimeType)`.

Comment: Deep apologizes for this. I switched from createFile(content) to createFile(name, content, mimetype) and I'd genuinely bet my life on the fact it had worked on my account. But it's clear I was wrong. So I changed to HTTPResponse.getblob().getAs('application/pdf').setName('filename'); and, obviously, it works.
Thanks for your patience having pointing this lousy mistake from me. And apologizes again.

Comment: No need  to apologize. Your question was well researched and had all the information. That's all that mattered and it even got a upvote.